# WSO2 IS 5.0.0 Hashing passwords for old users

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Im using the default WSO2 IS ldap store and it was configured to store passwords in plain text, and they indeed were in plain text.
Then I enabled the password hashing in WSO2 IS as described here:
http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/06/10/user-password-hashing-with-wso2-identity-server-wso2is/

It works for new users, but the old users (before the password hashing is enabled) are still with plain text values.

Can I trigger somehow the password hashing for these users?

Comment: Wouldn't it more effective to hash the password on the LDAP level? I mean - you cannot have the passwords hashed from some users and plain for others :/ You still may write your own userstore, but I'd suggest to migrate the plain LDAP passwords to hashed on the LDAP level..

Comment: Any suggestions or advices how I can migrate them on LDAP level?

Comment: What LDAP do you have in mind? (I've never used plain passwords in LDAP )

Comment: The embedded ldap in WSO2 IS

Comment: in the identity/embedded-ldap.xml there should be property passwordType, the default value is SHA. If it was "plain text", maybe you could switch it back to SHA or better SSHA. However - the migration needs to be done manually (I mean - write a small utility for the one-time job)